# Are there Chinese classical liberal intellectuals/politicians?

Tags: china, liberalism

Are there Chinese classical liberal intellectuals/politicians?

By Chinese I mean ethnic Chinese (華人 *huárén*) who were born and lived until at least their 20 years old in [Greater China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_China) (mainland China, Taiwan, Hong Kong, Macau, Singapore, Malaysia). It can possibly include Chinese people who emigrated later in their lives (after 20 years old) in non-sinitic countries (e.g. Europe and the US). Don't have in mind Chinese-American, Chinese-European, etc. which relates to a separate (interesting) question, IMO.

By classical liberalism I mean the advocacy for a socio-economic-political system combining : rule of law, equality before the law, representative democracy, separation of church and state, separation of powers, civil freedom (freedom of speech, of the press, of association), constitutionalism, parliamentarianism, and free-market capitalism and limited government, tolerance (regarding religions and other cultures), plus a great emphasis given to individualism and reason/science, as opposed to traditions and religions.

Hu Yaobang 胡耀邦, Zhao Ziyang 赵紫阳 may be the two politicians most close to classical liberalism.

Otherwise, the others would be more close to liberal conservatism (advocating for western liberal institutions, even science, but conserving Chinese traditional spirit): Zhang Zhidong 張之洞, Yan Fu 嚴復, Kang Youwei 康有為, Sun Yat-sen 孫中山, Liang Qichao 梁啓超, Lee Teng-Hui 李登輝, James Soong 宋楚瑜, Eric Chu  朱立倫, etc. To some extent, Hu Shih 胡適 also belongs to this trend.

Many Chinese intellectuals/politicians are conservatives, with a renewal in recent years: Zhang Binglin 章炳麟, Chiang Kai-shek 蔣介石, Feng Youlan 馮友蘭, Zhang Weiwei 張維為 etc.

The Taiwanese social democrats, affiliated to the Democratic Progressive Party 民進黨 *mínjìndǎng* (e.g. Yao Chia-wen 姚嘉文, Tsai Ing-wen 蔡英文) are social democrats, which is not classical liberalism, and they are also ethno-nationalist (c.f. Pan-Green Coalition), while ethno-nationalism is contrary to classical liberalism.

Then there are of course the numerous communists: Chen Duxiu 陳獨秀, Mao Zedong 毛澤東, etc.

And there are left-wing anarchists like Cai Yuanpei 蔡元培, Li Shizheng 李石曾, Wu Zhihui 吳稚暉, Zhang Renjie 張人傑, Ba Jin 巴金.

Liu Xiaobo 劉曉波 was very supportive of the Western liberal-democratic system, but made the claim that China must be colonized for at least hundred years by the West, which is not in line with classical liberalism.

I am not clear about Deng Xiaoping 鄧小平, but he was not a classical liberal for sure.

Comment: To me it's generally very hard to apply the term "classical liberal" to politicians as opposed to philosophers. If you disagree, examples would help.

Comment: @BrianZ In the limits of my knowledge: classical liberal politicians might have been most U.S. Founding Fathers. Today, I would say most Western politicians are either social-democrats or liberal conservatives, that is, IMO, not classical liberals, indeed. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: You mention Zhang Zhidong who died in 1909, Chiang Kai-shek who died in 1975. What sort of time-frame are you interested in? Also, Wikipedia has a list of [American politicians of Chinese descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_politicians_of_Chinese_descent) - possibly one of these? Or [other lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Politicians_of_Chinese_descent) for ethnic Chinese in other liberal, democratic countries?

Comment: @StuartF What sort of time-frame are you interested in? The last one century and a half or so. American politicians of Chinese descent is not what I had in mind. I'm thinking about people born in Greater China (by saying "overseas" I was thinking about people who emigrated to overseas)

Comment: @Starckman The only concrete example you've given of classical liberals are the US Founding Fathers who were very much a product of an an earlier era then the one you you're interested in. The question is very unlikely to be answerable without a lot more specificity.

Comment: @StuartF "The only concrete example you've given of classical liberals are the US Founding Fathers" of classical liberal **policitians**. In my question, I don't limit to politicians

Comment: Elaine Chao would probably fit your criteria.